# How to exchange the total if the item in holder had remove?

Tags: android

I can remove the item in holder but the price doesn't exchange. i had try to make the data remove but it's non sense too

i had try make the sub been minus but's still it's doesn't work on it i had the for list on the holder to made the price exchange it doesn't help through too

One Fragment.java

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View krnjg =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_keranjang,container,false);

    RecyclerView rec = krnjg.findViewById(R.id.rc1);

    LinearLayoutManager aw1 =new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    rec.setLayoutManager(aw1);


    madapter = new ProductAdapter(getContext(), example, getLayoutInflater());
    rec.setAdapter(madapter);
    madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    total = krnjg.findViewById(R.id.vtotal);
    btnpesan = krnjg.findViewById(R.id.btnpsn);

    for (int i = 0;i < example.size();i++){
        sub = sub + example.get(i).getPrice();

    }
    Locale locale = new Locale("in","ID");

    NumberFormat formatrupiah = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    total.setText(formatrupiah.format(sub));
```

Product adapter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Locale locale = new Locale("in","ID");

    NumberFormat formatrupiah = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    holder.nmPro.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.imge.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getProductImage());
    holder.hrg.setText(formatrupiah.format(mData.get(position).getPrice()));
    holder.cd.setActivated(mData.get(position).selected);
    holder.del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mData.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            double sub = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i<example.size();i++){

                sub -= example.get(i).getPrice();
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(mCon,"Barang "+holder.nmPro.getText()+" di hapus dari keranjang",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

i expect that the holder won't worked even the data that was holder it for just on that view not on the fragment that used to handle or maybe another ways to find it out because the total and the recycler is on different fragment that there is on adapter and fragment it's self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been solved this I just used a new classes to hold the click and price even I delete the item the price still same, which else item still on there. So this is I used for

```
public double getTotalPrice() {
    double totalPrice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); ++i) {
        totalPrice = totalPrice + mData.get(i).getPrice();
    }
    return totalPrice;
}
```

this class to get the total price on adapter and I got the class on holder too. For when I deleted the item the price is still same which item still on there like this I used it for

```
holder.del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mData.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            tvTotal.setText(formatrupiah.format(getTotalPrice()));
            Toast.makeText(mCon,"Barang "+holder.nmPro.getText()+" di hapus dari keranjang",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

mData is to get the data product from other activity I inputed and remove is to remove item from the cart and tvTotal is the price whenever the price inputed it can be deleted using this class on holder